# How data transfer will cost on my Azure project setup

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have built one utility (startup task) for end user Azure application.
That start-up task is going to post some of data from that webrole application (hosted on any region as per end user choice) to database (Hosted on East Asia) through REST API (Hosted on East Asia).

So if end user has hosted their application on same region (East Asia) then Azure doesn't cost anything for data transfer to me as well as for end user (correct me if I understood wrong).

In another case if end user has hosted their application on another region then it will cost to end user to transfer data to REST API that is on another region.

What I have done to reduce this cost, I have set up REST API in all of regions and in startup task tell user to set path of specific REST API according to region where they are going to deploy their application. Now in this case end user doesn't cost anything for data transfer But My REST API (hosted in different region ) will transfer data to database (hosted on East Asia) so it will cost me for that as well as for to host REST API on all regions to reduce end user cost.

In the case above is there a way to reduce cost using shared database and removing multiple REST API hosted on all region? Also please suggest if a better solution exists to reduce cost to me as well as for end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting scenario: You basically have your end-user deploying the app for themselves, to the region of choice? What is the purpose of the database upload via REST API: Backup, or for live data?

One thing I'm not understanding is the question about a shared database. From your description, there's already a shared database, as each user is pushing data through a REST API to a single database in East Asia. Is this not correct?

Based on the information you provided, where all data goes to one datacenter, I see 3 options, two that you already pointed out:

1. User hosts app in any of 8 datacenters, you host REST API in one datacenter. In this case, user gets best local app performance between on-prem and app, user pays for egress to your API, and user possibly sees latency when transferring data across datacenters.
2. User hosts app in any of 8 datacenters. You host REST API in all datacenters. User's data transfer is free to local REST API, and very fast. However, you then transfer data to East Asia database, which will cost you egress bandwidth if the user is not hosted in East Asia. Also you now have cost of many additional REST API instances.
3. User host ONLY in East Asia, along with your REST API and database. All datacenter bandwidth is free and fast. User may see latency connecting from on-prem to app, depending on where they're located.

In each case, you have the user deploying their own hosted service, which then talks to yours. Is it possible to optimize user cost by having them all access the same hosted service, but with different credentials?

For your cost, hosting a REST API in every datacenter seems like a large expense, considering you need at least 2 instances running in each datacenter to obtain Windows Azure's uptime SLA. But... again, I don't exactly understand your app's scenario.

Comment: To continue on option 2, you could host a service in East Asia just in  front of the database. The REST API would not connect to the database directly, but would go through the service hosted in East Asia. The advantage here is that you can compress the data (combined with protobuf for example) before sending it to East Asia which would lower the data transfer cost.

Comment: @David 1)Yes end user has own choice to deploying on any region 2) We are posting real time data (perfmon data) to database using stratup task and REST 3)Using Shared database means if i can host database(partial)  in on all regions related only for realtime data and process that data from one main Database(hosted on East Asia) and removing REST intermediate call.

Comment: @Sandrino It is depend on end user choice where he want to host his application according to his convenience. my purpose is giving him just stratup task to get some data from there to my Application & database.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, it seems the scenario is a bit strange. If you’re providing a package that end users can host using their own Windows Azure account, why let them use their own database as well? Or do you mean the you’re providing end users the source code of your project as a sample? In any case, I think it is better to ask end users to provide their own database account. If you want to design a REST API for yourself, then host it in your own Windows Azure service. Please do not distribute the package to your end users. In addition, for more information about billing, you can also contact our customer support on https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?prid=14234&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: You understood something wrong i am not providing any sample to end user. i have utility by which end user can monitor their azure application. that's it! and it's all about to saving cost for end user and my project setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, it is better to ask the customers to provide their own database. If you need to use your own database, it is hard to save cost on your side. You can use multiple databases hosted in different data centers. But obviously that requires more cost. You can also use a single database, but then it is inevitable that some users will transfer data from another data center. However, you can ask the users to pay for the cost by increasing the price of your product. But looks like better to ask the user to provide their own database (they can even choose on-premises databases if they like). This also helps to increase security, since users' data would not be shared.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.